# React-router вместе с Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Нужна ваша помощь. Я беру данные с API и отрисовываю их. Также я пытаюсь сделать переход на каждый отдельный продукт с помощью React-router. Но переход у меня не происходит, а в url у меня постоянно добавляется / products. Как сделать нормальный переход на компонента Product Detail? Спасибо

Products.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {products_are_loaded} from "../Redux/Action_creators";
import {Link, Route, BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import {Product_Detail} from "./Product_Detail";

export let Products = () => {

let dispatch = useDispatch();
let all_products = useSelector(({products_reducer : {all_products}}) => all_products)

let fetchProducts = async () => {
    try {
        let response = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
        let json = await response.json();
        console.log(json)
        dispatch(products_are_loaded(json));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts()
},[])
return (<Router>
        <div className="products_page">
        {all_products.map(el =>
        <div key={el.id} className="different_product">
            <div>
                <Link to={`products/${el.id}`}><p>{el.title}</p></Link>
            </div>
            <div> <img src={el.image} className="product_image"/> </div>
            <div> <button>Add to cart</button> </div>
        </div>)}
            
        </div>
        </Router>)
}
```

Product_detail.js

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import {different_product_are_loaded} from "../Redux/Action_creators";

export let Product_Detail = () => {
let {id} = useParams();
let dispatch = useDispatch();
let product_details = useSelector(({products_reducer : {different_product}}) => different_product);

let fetchProductDifferent = async () => {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${id}`)
        let json = await response.json();
        dispatch(different_product_are_loaded(json));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    fetchProductDifferent()
},[])
return (<div>Product Details</div>)
}
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import {All_products} from "./Components/All_products";
import {Cart} from "./Components/Cart";
import {Link, Route, BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import {Product_Detail} from "./Components/Product_Detail";
function App() {
return (<Router>

<div>
    <header className="header">
        <Link to={'/cart'}>Go to my cart</Link>
        <br/>
        <Link to={'/products'}>All products</Link>
    </header>

    <Route path={'/cart'} component={Cart}/>
    <Route path={'/products'} component={All_products}/>
    <Route path={'/products/:id'} component={Product_Detail}/>
</div>
      </Router>);
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы в url постоянно не добавлялся `/products` необходимо добавить `/` в начале пути:

```
<Link to={`/products/${el.id}`}><p>{el.title}</p></Link>
```

Соответственно нужен слэш и в `Route`:

```
<Route path="/products/:id" component={Product_Detail}/>
```

Так же внёс некоторые изменения: Теперь можно заходить на продукты и по ссылке на продукт открываются детали продукта. Добавил кнопку назад. Вот изменения:

All_products.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { products_are_loaded } from "../Redux/Action_creators";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export let All_products = () => {
  let dispatch = useDispatch();
  let all_products = useSelector(
    ({ products_reducer: { all_products } }) => all_products
  );

  let fetchProducts = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
      let json = await response.json();
      console.log(json);
      dispatch(products_are_loaded(json));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="products_page">
      {all_products.map((el) => (
        <div key={el.id} className="different_product">
          <Link to={`/products/${el.id}`}>
            <p>{el.title}</p>
            {el.id}
          </Link>
          <img src={el.image} className="product_image" />
          <button>Add to cart</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Product_Detail.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { different_product_are_loaded } from "../Redux/Action_creators";

export const Product_Detail = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const { title, description } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.products_reducer.different_product
  );

  const fetchProductDifferent = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products/${id}`);
      const json = await response.json();
      dispatch(different_product_are_loaded(json));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProductDifferent();
  }, []);

  const goBackHandler = () => {
    history.goBack();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Product {id} Detail</h1>
      <div>Title: {title}</div>
      <div>Description: {description}</div>
      <button onClick={goBackHandler}> Go Back</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import { All_products } from "./Components/All_products";
import { Cart } from "./Components/Cart";
import { Link, Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Product_Detail } from "./Components/Product_Detail";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <header className="header">
          <Link to={"/cart"}>Go to my cart</Link>
          <br />
          <Link to={"/products"}>All products</Link>
        </header>
        <Route path={"/cart"} component={Cart} />
        <Route path={"/products/:id"} component={Product_Detail} />
        <Route exact path={"/products"} component={All_products} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Так же залил на GitHub:  https://github.com/KonstantinModin/temp2

Comment: Спасибо. url перестала формироваться, но страница и дальше не отрисовывается

Comment: Этот проект есть на Гитхабе ?

Comment: https://github.com/Dmytrii9Cherniak/redux_react_example

Comment: Внёс дополнения в ответ .

Comment: Возникли вопросы?